# java spring boot hibernate doesnt update existing object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Im coding along with some udemy tutorial but i try to use thymeleaf instead of jsp. This is my form html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="eng">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Save Customer</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/style.css}" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/add-customer-style.css}" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
      <h2>CRM - Customer Relationship Manager</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <h3>Save Customer</h3>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/customer/saveCustomer}" th:object="${customer}" method="post">

      <!--need to associate this data with customer id-->
      <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}">

      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><label for="">First name:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{firstName}"></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td><label for="">Last name:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{lastName}"></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td><label for="">email:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{email}"></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td><label for=""></label></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="save" class="save"></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </form>

    <p>
      <a th:href="@{/customer/list}">Back to list</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

and this is my dao impl:

```html
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
 
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import java.util.List;
 
@Repository
public class CustomerDAOImpl implements CustomerDAO {
 
    //need to inject the session factory
    private SessionFactory hibernateFactory;
 
    @Autowired
    public CustomerDAOImpl(EntityManagerFactory factory) {
        if(factory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class) == null){
            throw new NullPointerException("factory is not a hibernate factory");
        }
        this.hibernateFactory = factory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
    }
 
    @Override
    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
 
        //get the current hibernate session
        var currentSession = hibernateFactory.openSession();
 
        //create a query... sort by last name
        var theQuery = currentSession.createQuery("from Customer order by lastName", Customer.class);
 
        // execute query and get result list
 
        //return the results
        return theQuery.getResultList();
    }
 
    @Override
    public void saveCustomer(Customer theCustomer) {
//        get current hibernate session
        var currentSession = hibernateFactory.openSession();
 
//        save the customer... finally LOL
        currentSession.saveOrUpdate(theCustomer);
    }
 
    @Override
    public Customer getCustomer(int theId) {
//        get the current hibernate session
        var currentSession = hibernateFactory.openSession();
 
//        now retrieve/read from database using the primary key
        return currentSession.get(Customer.class, theId);
    }
```

when i click update, it fills form with object's data that i want to update. But after clicking save nothing changes. Any idea why? Im wasting second day trying to make it work...

PS
Maybe something is wrong with session factory?

Or with hidden input?

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question instead of linking to pastecode.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please don't post links to code, xml etc. instead include them in your question.

Comment: Well you are bypassing spring transaction management and why on earth use the `SessionFactory` instead of the regular `Entitymanager`.

Comment: Because session factory was used in tutorial. As a begginer i dont know which one is better.

Comment: Ah, man! Its working! Please, replay to my topic so i can mark the solution :) I used entityManager instead of session and all is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `@Transactional` on the service method that calls `saveCustomer`